# Evaluate the line integral of a parabola

Tags: calculus, integration, multivariable-calculus, line-integrals

How can I evaluate :

$$\int_{C} y \;dx + x^2 \; dy$$

where $C$ is the parabola define by

$$y=4x-x^2 \quad \text{from } \; (4,0) \; \text{ to } \; (1,3).$$

---

Do I need to parameterize the parabola?

Comment: Typically you should indicate the parameterization used...in this case there is a natural one which is to use x as the parameter

Comment: Note the orientation of the curve as well.

Comment: Ok... So, how can I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

$$\because y = 4x-x^2 , \therefore \frac{dy}{dx} = 4-2x , \therefore dy = (4-2x)dx $$
Hence,
$$\int_{C} y \;dx + x^2 \; dy = \int_{4}^{1} 4x-x^2 dx + \int_{4}^{1} x^2 (4-2x)dx$$
$$\implies \int_4^1 4x-x^2+4x^2-2x^3$$
$$\implies \int_4^1 4x+3x^2-2x^3$$
$$\implies (2x^2+x^3-\frac{x^4}{2})_4^1$$
$$\implies (2+1-\frac{1}{2}) - (32+64-128)$$
$$\implies 35-\frac{1}{2}$$
$$\implies \frac{69}{2}$$

Comment: Isn't $\int_{4}^{1} x^2 \cdot (4-2x) \; dx$?

Comment: @hlapointe : thanks for pointing it out, i've corrected my answer now.

Answer (score 0):

hint:

The points on the parabola are $P=(x,y)=(x,4x-x^2)$ for $4\ge x\ge 1$ and
$$
dy=\frac{dy}{dx}dx=(4-2x)dx
$$

can you do from this?